# Convert nested list to dataframe: extract only specific elements of interest

Tags: r, tidyr, nested-lists, purrr, tibble

I've seen many similar questions, but couldn't adapt to my situation. I have data that comes as a nested list, and want to convert it to a data frame in a certain way.

```r
my_data_object <-
  list(my_variables = list(
    age = list(
      type = "numeric",
      originType = "slider",
      originSettings = structure(list(), .Names = character(0)),
      originIndex = 5L,
      title = "what is your age?",
      valueDescriptions = NULL
    ),
    med_field = list(
      type = "string",
      originType = "choice",
      originSettings = structure(list(), .Names = character(0)),
      originIndex = 6L,
      title = "what medical branch are you at?",
      valueDescriptions = list(card = "Cardiology", ophth = "Ophthalmology",
                               derm = "Dermatology")
    ),
    covid_vaccine = list(
      type = "string",
      originType = "choice",
      originSettings = structure(list(), .Names = character(0)),
      originIndex = 8L,
      title = "when do you plan to get vaccinated?",
      valueDescriptions = list(
        next_mo = "No later than next month",
        within_six_mo = "No later than six months from now",
        never = "I will not get vaccinated"
      )
    )
  ))
```

#### Desired Output

```r
  var_name      type    originType title                              
  <chr>         <chr>   <chr>      <chr>                              
1 age           numeric slider     what is your age?                  
2 med_field     string  choice     what medical branch are you at?    
3 covid_vaccine string  choice     when do you plan to get vaccinated?
```

#### My unsuccessful attempt

```r
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)

my_data_object %>% 
  enframe() %>% 
  unnest_longer(value) %>% 
  unnest(value)

## # A tibble: 18 x 3
##    name         value            value_id     
##    <chr>        <named list>     <chr>        
##  1 my_variables <chr [1]>        age          
##  2 my_variables <chr [1]>        age          
##  3 my_variables <named list [0]> age          
##  4 my_variables <int [1]>        age          
##  5 my_variables <chr [1]>        age          
##  6 my_variables <NULL>           age          
##  7 my_variables <chr [1]>        med_field    
##  8 my_variables <chr [1]>        med_field    
##  9 my_variables <named list [0]> med_field    
## 10 my_variables <int [1]>        med_field    
## 11 my_variables <chr [1]>        med_field    
## 12 my_variables <named list [3]> med_field    
## 13 my_variables <chr [1]>        covid_vaccine
## 14 my_variables <chr [1]>        covid_vaccine
## 15 my_variables <named list [0]> covid_vaccine
## 16 my_variables <int [1]>        covid_vaccine
## 17 my_variables <chr [1]>        covid_vaccine
## 18 my_variables <named list [3]> covid_vaccine
```

I'm trying to get this using `tidyverse` functions, but so far it seems I'm not headed the right direction. I Will be grateful for guidance.

#### EDIT

Unlike the example data I provided originally, in reality my data comes in a bit different hierarchy. I thought this would be simple to generalize once I have the method but turns it's not. So if we consider that data comes such as the following, but truly I only care about the `my_variables` sub-list.

```r
my_data_object_2 <-
  list(
  other_variables = list(
    whatever_var_1 = list(
      type = "numeric",
      originType = "slider",
      originSettings = structure(list(), .Names = character(0)),
      originIndex = 5L,
      title = "blah question",
      valueDescriptions = NULL
    )
  ),
  my_variables = list(
    age = list(
      type = "numeric",
      originType = "slider",
      originSettings = structure(list(), .Names = character(0)),
      originIndex = 5L,
      title = "what is your age?",
      valueDescriptions = NULL
    ),
    med_field = list(
      type = "string",
      originType = "choice",
      originSettings = structure(list(), .Names = character(0)),
      originIndex = 6L,
      title = "what medical branch are you at?",
      valueDescriptions = list(card = "Cardiology", ophth = "Ophthalmology",
                               derm = "Dermatology")
    ),
    covid_vaccine = list(
      type = "string",
      originType = "choice",
      originSettings = structure(list(), .Names = character(0)),
      originIndex = 8L,
      title = "when do you plan to get vaccinated?",
      valueDescriptions = list(
        next_mo = "No later than next month",
        within_six_mo = "No later than six months from now",
        never = "I will not get vaccinated"
      )
    )
  )
)
```

So how could I "zoom in"/"extract" `my_variables` and *only then* get the table I specified in "Desired Output" above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `flatten` the object, use `enframe` and `unnest_wider` to create new columns.

```
library(tidyverse)

my_data_object %>% 
  flatten() %>%
  tibble::enframe() %>%
  unnest_wider(value)
  
#  name          type    originType originIndex title                               valueDescriptions
#  <chr>         <chr>   <chr>            <int> <chr>                               <list>           
#1 age           numeric slider               5 what is your age?                   <NULL>           
#2 med_field     string  choice               6 what medical branch are you at?     <named list [3]> 
#3 covid_vaccine string  choice               8 when do you plan to get vaccinated? <named list [3]>
```

You can then drop the columns that you don't need.

---

To use only `my_data_object_2$my_variables` :

```
my_data_object_2$my_variables %>%
  tibble::enframe() %>%
  unnest_wider(value)
```

Comment: this `tidyvrese` solution is neat. Could you please take a look at my recent edit to the post? Basically I'm looking for an intermediate step between `my_data_object` and the other functions in the pipe, as I want to focus only on `my_variables` sub-list. I tried including `purrr::chuck(my_variables)` in this pipe but got an error.

Comment: @Emman Did you try my answer replacing `my_data_object` with `my_data_object_2` ? It does give a 4 X 6 tibble. You may remove the rows/columns that you don't want from there.

Comment: Yes, I tried it on `my_data_object_2` and it works as you described, but it would be cleaner if I could just focus on `my_variables` which by nature hosts all the `name`s I need, instead of getting a gigantic tibble (in my real data) and then having to `filter` by specific names. I'm trying to automate as much as I can...

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I replaced `my_data_object_2$my_variables` with `purrr:chuck()` such that the pipe is now: `my_data_object_2 %>% purrr:chuck("my_variables") %>% tibble::enframe() %>% tidyr::unnest_wider(value)`

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over `my_data_object` tibblifying the indicated columns and putting it all together using `map_dfr` (or maybe `fun(my_data_object$my_variables)` is sufficient depnding on what the general case is).  There are no missing fields in the example data but if any of the 3 spec fields can be missing then add `.default = NA` as an `lcol_chr` argument to that field spec.

```
library(purrr)
library(tibblify)

spec <-  lcols(
  lcol_chr("type"),
  lcol_chr("originType"),
  lcol_chr("title")
)
fun <- function(x) cbind(var_name = names(x), tibblify(x, spec))

map_dfr(my_data_object, fun)
```

giving:

```
       var_name    type originType                               title
1           age numeric     slider                   what is your age?
2     med_field  string     choice     what medical branch are you at?
3 covid_vaccine  string     choice when do you plan to get vaccinated?
```

Depending on what the general case is this simplification by @mgirlich (which is similar to the alternative in the introduction to this answer) may work.  `spec` is from above.

```
library(tibblify)

cbind(
  var_name = names(my_data_object[[1]]),
  tibblify(my_data_object[[1]], spec)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `lapply` as usual to select specific columns, just `rbind` them.

```
res <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, 
               lapply((my_data_object)[[1]], `[`, c("type", "originType", "title")))
res
#                  type originType                               title
# age           numeric     slider                   what is your age?
# med_field      string     choice     what medical branch are you at?
# covid_vaccine  string     choice when do you plan to get vaccinated?
```

If you want row names to first column, do:

```
`rownames<-`(cbind(var=rownames(res), res), NULL)
#             var    type originType                               title
# 1           age numeric     slider                   what is your age?
# 2     med_field  string     choice     what medical branch are you at?
# 3 covid_vaccine  string     choice when do you plan to get vaccinated?
```